# Auto mirroring doesn't work in menu icons in Android version 8 and above

Tags: android, android-studio, svg, vector

I was trying to use vector with auto mirroring option in `Menu` of `Fragment`. But with RTL Locale it doesn't rotate 180 degree from the default version.

This is xml's content of vector:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:pathData="M2.01,21L23,12 2.01,3 2,10l15,2 -15,2z" />
</vector>
```

As mentioned in title, this issue is accrued only in menu item and android version 8 and above. Rest of the situations are OK.